# How to scope credentials on Google App Engine?

Tags: authentication, google-app-engine, credentials

We are trying to give an App Engine app the same scoped privileges as the logged in user.

We tried using the code below from [this documentation](https://google-auth.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/google.oauth2.service_account.html):

```
    credentials = GoogleCredentials.get_application_default()
    scoped_credentials = credentials.with_scopes(['my@emailaddress.com'])
```

But we are getting this error:

```
'AppAssertionCredentials' object has no attribute 'with_scopes'
```

What are we doing wrong?

Comment: hi, can you show the full traceback?

Comment: Please include most context for your source code. What libraries are you importing?